# Find the Size (or Length) of custom datatype

Tags: java

I have a similar cases with one of the user that posted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20410615/java-arraylist-deck-class) before. It is a card game, and we have to create a new data type called `card` where it contains "rank" and "suit".

How to get the size of arrayList of card when we can't use `size()` or `length` since it is not a string?

Update: I can't use `size()` because when I write it, it will gives warning `cannot resolve method 'size()'`

```
    `ArrayList<Card> hisCards;
    hisCards = new ArrayList<Card>();`

public static int checkColumn(Card cardArray) {
    int cardSize = cardArray.size();
    if (cardSize == 0) {
       return 1;
   }
   return 0;
```

}

I'm just planning to pass it through a function later. `cardArray` will be substituted by `hishand`
Maybe I'm just doing it wrong?

Comment: you get the size of an arrayList by doing exactly that: .size(), how else?

Comment: Do you mean size in bytes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any sizeof-like method in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370288/is-there-any-sizeof-like-method-in-java)

Comment: if you cannot use size(), just make a variable that count the cards everytime the user add or remove card from deck

Comment: @Stultuske but why I got a warning when I used it?

Comment: @MasAdam: maybe you used it wrong. show your code.

Comment: @MasAdam: yes, you can use .size(), but you have to use it correctly.

Comment: `cannot resolve method 'size()'` I supposed you mean `error` not `warning`. You should show the line or snippet of codes where you got the error.

Comment: The name of your list is hisCards, not cardArray.

Comment: @MasAdam Please show how you define `cardArray`. Is it an array or arrayList??

Comment: I've updated already

Comment: @MasAdam Take a look at my solution again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Update: I can't use size() because when I write it, it will gives warning cannot resolve method 'size()'

Ensure you are invoking the `size()` method from the correct instance. This is an example of how you can get the size from an arraylist:

```
ArrayList<Card> hisCards = new ArrayList<Card>();
int numOfCards = hisCards.size();    //get number of elements from hisCards
```

**Edit:** You are invoking `size()` on a Card object instead of an arraylist !

---

Change your method to:

```
public static int checkColumn(ArrayList<Card> cardArray)
```

Comment: @MasAdam If your intention is to pass an arraylist such as `hisHand` into the method, you can change it as I suggested above. Then you still can get size by invoking `int cardSize = cardArray.size()`. If you are passing an array into that method, you will be invoking cardArray.length instead.

Answer (score 1):

The `size()` method is not a method of `String`, it's a method of `Collection`, which means that `new ArrayList<Card>().size()` is valid.

The `size()`-method returns the number of elements in the collection.

With your code example, `hisCards.size()` should not result in a compilation error.

Your variable named `cardArray` is not an `array`(or an `ArrayList`), it's just a `Card`. Of course, this has no `size()`-method (unless you actually made one.)

Comment: but why I got a warning when I used it?

Comment: How can I possibly answer that? What kind of warning?